# Is there a better way to assign many values to variables and echo them in order in PHP?

Tags: php

OK, at the top of my page I have a bunch of php variables like this:

```
<?php 
$description_1 = 'This and that';
$description_2 = 'This and this and that';
?>
```

And this data is then pulled into HTML markup using the echo syntax, but the thing is that I have created hundreds of similar code to allow for the above variables to be echoed, in other words, image the below:

```
<p><?php echo $description_1; ?></p>
```

and then repeated 200 times:

```
<p><?php echo $description_2; ?></p>
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I am sure there is....

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need them to be variables? Could it be one array `$descriptions[] = 'This and that';`? Then iterate over the array.

Comment: Repeated in the same file? If you just want a better way to map data from the server onto some "HTML", you could look into templating engines e.g. [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Answer (score 4):

As stated by [@chris85](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886264/php-include-should-be-basic-but-i-am-a-bit-confused#comment70954880_41886264), use arrays:

```
$description = [
  'This and that',
  'This and this and that'
];

foreach($description as $value){
  echo "<p>$value</p>";
}
```

The first index is `0`, incrementing after each assignment so:

```
echo $description[1]; // This and this and that
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$description = array('This and that', 'This and that and that');
foreach($description as $row){
  echo '<p>'.$row.'</p>'
}
```

or

```
$description = 'This and that';
$description .= 'This and that and that';
```